# Get acces to handles while in a Callback function

Tags: matlab

I have a Problem with my callback functions.
I wrote a small Example For it :

```
function drawMeAnImrect

  Numbers = [1,2,3];

  h  = imrect();

  h.addNewPositionCallback(@(h)Randomfunc(Numbers));

  h.wait();

  Numbers = [1,2,3,4];

end



function Randomfunc(Numbers)

  disp(Numbers)

end
```

everytime i move the rect i will print the Numbers 1,2 and 3, even if i change the Numbers. Ist there a way to avoid this ? It works with global variables but i dont wanna use many global variables. I hope someone can help me. Thx

Comment: What do you really want to do? Print the numbers `[1 2 3 4]` after the rectangle was created? That's not clear to me sorry

Comment: As your code is written, this is a logical behavior. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: Well i Work with a Gui and i wanna give the Randomfunc handles, so i can Change in the Randomfunc Elements of the handle i gave